# Rake aborted... table 'users' already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have created a database with devise and the nifty generator. I'm trying to make a new database with the nifty generator (`rails g nifty:scaffold Asset user_id:integer`), but when I try to migrate the database (`rake db:migrate`), I get the following error:

```
charlotte-dator:showwwdown holgersindbaek$ rake db:migrate
==  DeviseCreateUsers: migrating ==============================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `encrypted_password` varchar(128) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `reset_password_token` varchar(255), `reset_password_sent_at` datetime, `remember_created_at` datetime, `sign_in_count` int(11) DEFAULT 0, `current_sign_in_at` datetime, `last_sign_in_at` datetime, `current_sign_in_ip` varchar(255), `last_sign_in_ip` varchar(255), `name` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm following a tutorial and have quite a hard time understanding why this happens. Can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The migration is trying to create a table that already exists in your database.

Try to remove the user table from your database. Something went wrong with you migration process. You should also compare your schema.rb version with your db/migrate/*.rb files.

**Clarification:**

It seems that many SO users don't agree with my reply, either because they consider it inaccurate or not recommended.

Removing a table is always destructive, and I think that everyone understands that.

I should have mentioned [add_column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column), since the table was being created in another migration file.

Comment: Just delete the table? That's a horrible solution.

Comment: I would like to know your solution.

Comment: This obvious, but I want to clarify for anyone that does this... **Your data in that table will be lost**.

Comment: As others mentioned, the data will be lost if you drop the table. But the real reason this happens is because the migrations table gets out of sync. According to the table, Rails has not run your migration yet. But the table already exists, so either you manually created it, or (more likely) you edited the migration (perhaps to add a field) and ran it multiple times.  You can fix this "manually", by simply adding the migration number to the table so that Rails doesn't attempt to run it again.

Answer (score 66):

In your `create_users` migration (APP_ROOT/db/migrate/..), add `drop_table :users` right before `create_table :users` and run `rake db:migrate`. It will remove the users table before recreating it. You can remove that line of code after running this migration so it doesn't give you errors later on. Just a small fix if you dont have UI access to a database (on heroku, for example).

Comment: Both solutions semi-worked... It seemed that I really did something wrong in the toturial, so I took a couple of steps back and re-did it. Thanks a lot for the great solutions though.

Comment: This is obvious, but I want to clarify for anyone that does this... **Your data in that table will be lost**.

Comment: Never had this idea, pretty efficient!

Answer (score 22):

You need to drop that table from the sql lite console (You will lost all the data contained in it)

1. Access the sql lite console, type in terminal
   `mysql <DB NAME HERE>`
2. Drop table (dont forget the last **;** (semicolon))
   `drop table table_name;`
3. run **db:migrate** again
   `bin/rake db:migrate`

Hope it helps, it worked for me

Comment: The question is about MySQL, not Sqlite.

Answer (score 18):

If you wanna play safe and don't want to lose any data then you can check if the table exists in your database.

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    if table_exists?(:users)
      # update or modify columns of users table here accordingly.
    else
      # create table and dump the schema here
    end
  end

  def down
    # same approach goes here but in the reverse logic
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

If you know the database was created properly, you can just comment out the creation part of the migration code.  For example:

```
Class ActsAsVotableMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
#    create_table :votes do |t|
#
#      t.references :votable, :polymorphic => true
#      t.references :voter, :polymorphic => true
#
#      t.boolean :vote_flag
#
#      t.timestamps
#    end
#
#    add_index :votes, [:votable_id, :votable_type]
#    add_index :votes, [:voter_id, :voter_type]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :votes
  end
end
```

If the table was created, but later commands weren't completed for some reason, you can just leave the later options for example:

```
Class ActsAsVotableMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
#    create_table :votes do |t|
#
#      t.references :votable, :polymorphic => true
#      t.references :voter, :polymorphic => true
#
#      t.boolean :vote_flag
#
#      t.timestamps
#    end

    add_index :votes, [:votable_id, :votable_type]
    add_index :votes, [:voter_id, :voter_type]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :votes
  end
end
```

If you don't have any significant data in your database to preserve however you can just have it drop the table and all the data and create it fresh.  For example (**notice the "drop_table :votes", in the self.up**):

```
class ActsAsVotableMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    drop_table :votes
    create_table :votes do |t|

      t.references :votable, :polymorphic => true
      t.references :voter, :polymorphic => true

      t.boolean :vote_flag

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :votes, [:votable_id, :votable_type]
    add_index :votes, [:voter_id, :voter_type]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :votes
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't delete tables. Data > migrations!

The version of the database already reflects the changes the error-causing migration is trying to add. In other words, if the migration could be skipped, then everything would be fine. Check the db_schema_migrations table and try inserting the version of the erroneous migration (e.x, 20151004034808). In my case this caused subsequent migrations to execute perfectly and everything seems fine.

Still not sure what caused this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is new and you don't care about the data in your database, simply:

```
rake db:reset
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an issue unique or more common to mysql in rails, possible having to do with the mysql2 gem itself.

I know this because I just switched from sqlite to mysql and just started having this problem systematically.

In my case, I simply commented out the code that had already run and ran the migration again (which I'm not adding more detail to because it looks like the guy above me did that).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to add Devise authentication to an existing Users table.

My solution: I found that I had two migrate files, both trying to create the Users table. So rather than deleting the table (probably not the best habit to form), I commented out the first (original) migrate file that created the Users table and then left the Devise migrate file as-is. Re-ran the migration and it worked fine.

As it turns out, the Devise file wasn't causing the problem; I can see that it is "changing" the table, not "creating it", which means that even without the devise installation, a db:migrate probably would have caused the same issue (though I haven't tested this).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **keep your data**, **rename the table**, but do it in the migration to save time, then remove it once the migration has ran.

Place at the top part of the **up** section of the migration file.

```
rename_table :users, :users2
```